# Swift super.init() - Property not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, class, init

I'm getting the error "Property 'self.directionsCompletionHandler' not initialized at super.init call" on the `super.init()` line. This worked fine right up until the most recent Xcode update (11.4).  Removing the `init()` or `super.init()` also cause errors. I'm not quite sure what it wants me to do.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

typealias DirectionsCompletionHandler = ((_ route:MKPolyline?, _ directionInformation:NSDictionary?, _ boundingRegion:MKMapRect?, _ error:String?)->())?

class MapManager: NSObject{

    fileprivate var directionsCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler
    fileprivate let errorNoRoutesAvailable = "No routes available"// add more error handling

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
fileprivate var directionsCompletionHandler:DirectionsCompletionHandler
```

with

```
fileprivate var directionsCompletionHandler: DirectionsCompletionHandler = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not making the `typealias`, itself, optional, but rather just a simple closure:

```
typealias DirectionsCompletionHandler = (_ route: MKPolyline?, _ directionInformation: NSDictionary?, _ boundingRegion: MKMapRect?, _ error: String?) -> Void
```

This is the standard convention when defining typealias for a closure.

And then define your `directionCompletionHandler` to make the optional behavior explicit:

```
fileprivate var directionsCompletionHandler: DirectionsCompletionHandler?
```

And the compiler has no trouble figuring out that it doesn’t need to be initialized.

Or, of course, you could make this initialization explicit if you wanted:

```
fileprivate var directionsCompletionHandler: DirectionsCompletionHandler? = nil
```